# lazy loading doesnt work on database first method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i'm working on Asp.Net MVC project and I use EF to access database. For some reasons I cant use code first so I'm using Database first method and lazyLoading doesn't work while it's enabled! for example I cant do some thing like the following code after disposal of dbContext:

```
public ActionResult ListAll()
{
    List<Album> albums = new List<Album>();
    using (newsDBEntities context = new newsDBEntities())
    {
         albums = context.Albums.ToList();
         return View(albums);
    }


    }
```

And the view 
    
    @foreach (project.Models.Album album in Model)
    {

```
    List<project.Models.Image> img = album.Images.Take(3).ToList();
    <div class="albumHolder">
    @foreach (var item in img)
    {
        <div class="imageHolder">
        <img src ="@item.imageURL" width="200px" height="200px" />
        </div>
    }
    <p class="albumP">@album.albumName</p>
    </div>
}
<div></div>
</div>
```

I get the following exception at the line which I am trying to take 3 element of model in the view: 
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection. 
I wonder why it shouldn't load images while lazy loading is enabled. and I also wonder why it's works when I do a similar code in Console app!

Comment: When the context is disposed there is no longer a connection to the database.  That being the case how would lazy loading load a navigation property without a connection to the database?

Comment: that's right but I used .toList() that should force the EF tu execute the query then the album should be a local variable

Comment: your `albums` is local, but your `Images` is not local...

Comment: but I've done same thing with code first with no problem :( I passed the album to the view and I could list all of it's images there

Comment: I don't know anything about your *other* code, you haven't listed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

OK, it seems that you're trying to do lazy loading in the view, which I think won't work. Instead, I think you should make sure all data that you need in the view is loaded in the controller. In your case I think you would need to include the Images detail data. Try changing your code in the controller to

```
// At the top of your class code:
using System.Data.Entity;

// And then inside the using clause:

albums = context.Albums.Include(x => x.Images).ToList();
```

This will make sure that the album's images are available in the view, hence no lazy loading is needed.

Comment: I know that will work but actually in the real code I pass the album to the view then in the view I try to take 3 element of album  then I get the exception, I want all of the images get loaded in album so I could use them without database connection

Comment: I edited my question this is the actual thing I'm trying to do

Comment: i had no idea Include existed... thats awesome.